# Replace Selection with Value from Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to replace my selection on one Workbook with the offset value from another.

```vb
Sub NameUpdate()
Dim cCell As Range, cRange As Range, sCell As Range, sRange As Range
Dim cLastRow As Long
Dim FindString As String
Dim wb As Workbook, sup As Worksheet
Set wb = Workbooks("MyWorkbook.xlsm")
Set sup = wb.Worksheets("Codes")
cLastRow = sup.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set cRange = sup.Range("A2:B" & cLastRow)
Set sRange = Selection
For Each sCell In sRange
    FindString = sCell.Value
    For Each cCell In cRange
        If cCell.Value = FindString Then
            sCell.Value = cCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End If
    Next cCell
Next sCell
End Sub
```

I tried to combine two macros that have worked. It does not give me an error but doesn't do anything. Google has not helped.

Comment: If it does nothing, then `If cCell.Value = FindString Then` is never true.

Comment: Hmm, the original code is use is:
`Dim cCell As Range, cRange As Range, sCell As Range, sRange As Range
Dim cLastRow As Long, sLastRow As Long
Dim FindString As String
cLastRow = sup.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
sLastRow = ctd.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set cRange = sup.Range("A2:B" & cLastRow)
Set sRange = ctd.Range("A2:G" & sLastRow)
For Each sCell In sRange
FindString = sCell.Value
For Each cCell In cRange
If cCell.Value = FindString Then
sCell.Value = cCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
End If
Next cCell
Next sCell`
Which replaces the value perfectly.

Comment: You could probably use `Application.Match` or `Range.Find`.

Comment: I will give that a try, thank you

Comment: I'm such an idiot, my target document had spaces in front of the value... so I added the line `sCell.Value = Trim(sCell.Value)` and now it works perfectly. Sorry about that. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code was fine, it was user error. There was a space in the target cells.

Added `sCell.Value = Trim(sCell.Value)`

Changed code to:

```
Sub NameUpdate()
Dim cCell As Range, cRange As Range, sCell As Range, sRange As Range
Dim cLastRow As Long
Dim FindString As String
Dim wb As Workbook, sup As Worksheet
Set wb = Workbooks("MyWorkbook.xlsm")
Set sup = wb.Worksheets("Codes")
cLastRow = sup.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set cRange = sup.Range("A2:B" & cLastRow)
Set sRange = Selection
For Each sCell In sRange
sCell.Value = Trim(sCell.Value)
FindString = sCell.Value
For Each cCell In cRange
If cCell.Value = FindString Then
sCell.Value = cCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
End If
Next cCell
Next sCell
End Sub
```

Works perfectly now, sorry!